# What is "srv_listen" permission used for?

Tags: permissions, location-services, textsecure, xprivacy

I've noticed (by using XPrivacy) that many applications (and some that has nothing to do with location, such as TextSecure) require the following permissions:

```
Location: srv_listen
Phone: srv_listen
```

(These permissions seem to be linked)

I failed to find any info on what are these permissions used for, neither what functionality may be harmed by blocking them.

I'd be glad if anyone here with some android programming knowledge can spill any light on it... 
What are they used for? What info may be accessed by granting those permissions? Is it actually providing any location info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain what 'srv_listen' really does but to find more info you can use the infobutton in Xprivacy next to the permission name.

[image]

There you will find that the actual permission is called ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and you'll find a link to the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int)).

I'm sorry that I can't help more.

Comment: Thanks for your insight!
It indeed tells that the permission is ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, I've checked it, and it also listen for the application in the App Ops.

However, under Play Store's "Permissions" listing no location access is mentioned (and I'm also using an Xposed module to provide more detailed listing there).
I also block Location access for that application by CM's Privacy Guard (App Ops).
Moreover, App Ops tells that ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION has been never actually used by the application, while XPrivacy requested the "SRV_LISTEN" permission several times.

Comment: So the bottom line it seems that SRV_LISTEN is not exacly asking for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, and remains quiet a mistery to me...

Comment: That sure sounds like one. Sorry I cant provide more insight. All those permissions in XP keep being a mystery to me.

Comment: One more comment on yours: I think i read somewhere that you shouldn't combine several permission managers. Not that you get into trouble! ;)

Comment: I'm aware about the "combining permission managers" thing. It's less messy than it sounds and safer than, say running two firewalls, for example. They're kinda work in sequential manner. I mainly use XPrivacy due to it's granular access, and App Ops (aka CM's Privacy Guard) is a backup option for the times Xposed Framework is down. Anyways, even though its still somewhat a mystery, thanks a lot for your assistance!!!